# Iterating 1 row at a time with massive amounts of links/joins

Tags: sql-server, join, iteration, row-number

Ok, basically what is needed is a way to have row numbers while using a lot of joins and having where clauses using these rownumbers.

such as something like

```
select ADDRESS.ADDRESS FROM ADDRESS 
INNER JOIN WORKHISTORY ON WORKHISTORY.ADDRESSRID=ADDRESS.ADDRESSRID
INNER JOIN PERSON ON PERSON.PERSONRID=WORKHISTORY.PERSONRID
WHERE PERSONRID=<some number> AND WORKHISTORY.ROWNUMBER=1
```

ROWNUMBER needs to be generated for this query on that one table though. So that if we want to access the second WORKHISTORY record's address, we could just go `WORKHISTORY.ROWNUMBER=2` and if say we had two address's that matched, we could cycle through the addresses for one WORKHISTORY record using `ADDRESS.ROWNUMBER=1` and `ADDRESS.ROWNUMBER=2`

This should be capable of being an automatically generated query. Thus, there could be more than 10 inner joins in order to get to the relevant table, and we need to be able to cycle through each table's record independently of the rest of the tables..

I'm aware there is the RANK and ROWNUMBER functions, but I'm not seeing how it will work for me because of all the inner joins

note: in this example query, ROWNUMBER should be automatically generated! It should never be stored in the actual table

Comment: Duplicated
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534240/mssql-select-statement-with-incremental-integer-column-not-from-a-table

Comment: let this be an extension of it then. Using that same rownumber technique on multiple joined tables. (I'm not concerned about pre-2005 compatibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a temp table?

I ask because you can write the code like this:

```
select a.field1, b.field2, c.field3, identity (int, 1,1)  as TableRownumber into #temp
from table1 a 
join table2 b on a.table1id = b.table1id
join table3 c on b.table2id = c.table2id

select * from #temp where ...
```

Comment: Could be concurrency issues, but using automatic temp-table name generating, it shouldn't be much of a problem.. this will probably work for me

Comment: Is it even barely efficient to create multiple temp tables, because I will need to be able to use this rownumber effect on each join, so is using up to 10 temp tables for one query a problem? (I'm not trying to preoptimize.. it just sounds a bit too crazy to be efficient)

Comment: If you have a lot of data in each and a lot of concurrent users , you may have a problem, but honestly you have to solve the problem first. Perhaps you will have some effieiency issues no matter how you solve this. You can index temp tables for your later queries involving them. I suppose you could build one temp table at the end that includes the ids from the other temp tables as well as the other info you want and then drop the first ten.  Could you use the actual id field in the tables involved  or use row number in the overall temp table in conjuntion with the id to do your comparisons?

Comment: no.. it must be exact because of how the intention is basically cycling through results with no idea as to what records will actually be needed..