# SQL - Update column for different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

After merging tables, I got the following result

```
| id | count | some_id |
| 0  |  0    |  1      |
| 1  |  1    |  1      |
| 2  |  2    |  1      |
| 3  |  7    |  1      |
| 4  |  12   |  1      |
| 5  |  1    |  2      |
| 6  |  2    |  2      |
| 7  |  5    |  2      |
and so on...
```

**Per `some_id`, I need to change the `count` to the correct counting sequence**

The result I would need is

```
| id | count | some_id |
| 0  |  0    |  1      |
| 1  |  1    |  1      |
| 2  |  2    |  1      |
| 3  |  3    |  1      |
| 4  |  4    |  1      |
| 5  |  0    |  2      |
| 6  |  1    |  2      |
| 7  |  2    |  2      |
and so on...
```

Assuming `some_id` is `0<some_id<n`

Is there a way I can do this? The only thing I'm thinking is using loops but are there any other ways besides that?

Comment: Use `Row_Number()` to increment your `count` column - Partitioning by your  `some_id` column and ordering by your `Id`  column http://stackoverflow.com/a/534280/1693085

Comment: You should rewrite the question with more information on what your are trying to accomplish.  Consider including how you you generate your first result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User **[ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)**

```
SELECT
      id,
      -1 + ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY some_id ORDER BY some_id) as [Count],
      some_id
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` starts from `1` and OP wanted the first row to be indexed with `0`, so you should decrement by one.

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes I saw that one, dont know why didnt include that.

Comment: Im still working on the proper sintax to add the `-1` and start at `0`

Comment: Awesome! It worked just the way I want it to. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DENSE_RANK to achieve the same:-

```
SELECT id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY some_id) AS 'Count', some_id
FROM your_table;
```